# How to fetch data from API and update cells and sections when scrolling up the tableView using willDisplay cell method?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am using tableView to show the data from API and i have sections and cells inside. When user scrolls down, my algorithm fetching the data according the date (for example today's data from API in on section, and when scrolling down, it fetches data from API again for new section with number of cells according to API) correctly, but i need to fetch previous date from API as scrolling down, when user scrolls up, it should show preview day. I have seen many answers for scroll down, but not up. Here is my little chunk of code:

```
           if order == 0 {

                let indexSet = IndexSet(arrayLiteral: 0)
                ByPassArray.insert(rootJSON, at: 0)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.scheduleTableView.insertSections(indexSet,          
                         with: 0)
                    self.scheduleTableView.reloadData()

                }
            }

            else {
                ByPassArray.append(rootJSON)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.scheduleTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried reading about implementing pagination in tableView? There are multiple tutorial available explaining that.

Comment: Yeah i did, but there are techniques that teaches only when user scrolls down and automatic update section and cell. However, what i need is when user scrolls up, it should generate section and cell and fill it with data from API

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get it right but you might want to implement the method

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

in your UITableViewDelegate and check for the cell at `indexPath.row == 0`

If you know that you're about to present the first cell of the tableview then you might want to start your API call and then do whatever you have to do.

Comment: Yeah i am checking if indexPath.section ==0 and indexPath.row ==0 call API fetch method, but the problem is when calling that method i need to insert new section with number of rows from api, then update tableView?